# getting undefined is not an object when using e.target

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select an element using e.target but I am getting the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target')"

my code is as follows:

```js
isRead();
    
function isRead(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('isRead')) {
    console.log('it is read');
  }
}

function createBook(book) {
  const readBtn   = document.createElement('button');
  const readInput = document.getElementById('readInput');

  readBtn.classList.add('libraryBtn');
  readBtn.classList.add('read');
  readBtn.textContent = 'Read?'

  if (readInput.checked) {
    readBtn.textContent = 'Read';
    readBtn.classList.add('isRead')
  }
```

Comment: You aren't passing the function anything at all, much less an event object.

Comment: sorry I am not following. Im not sure why I couldn't access my readBtn that was created using this method then checking if it has a isRead class? any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect an `event` object `e` being passed when you have a direct function call without a callback.

```
isRead();
```

Only if you call the function `isRead` when an event happens as a callback, will you have access to the event object `e`.

Something like:

```
document.querySelector('selectorElement').addEventListener("click",isRead);
```